# Insert data into database without waiting for it

Tags: php, mysql, insert

In my php script,I'm using PDO to insert csv data into database.

`$sqlsmttempl = 'INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)';`

But it took quite a long time for just few thousands records.How can I prevent clients from waiting for inserting?

I tried `INSERT DELAYED` , it dont' have any error but it seems no responses at all.

Any hints for it?Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried `INSERT DELAYED`, it dont' have any error but it seems no responses at all."? What are you expecting to happen that isn't?

Comment: @FrancisAvila The data will be inserted when table is not in use by any other thread?I read it from here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html

Comment: But what do you mean by "it seems no responses at all"? `INSERT DELAYED` will always report a successful insert no matter what, because it can't know if there's an error until it inserts, and it can't insert now.

Comment: @FrancisAvila When I select csv file and click upload,it didn't show me any message and just like refreshing the page.I will try in other query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to not have the client wait for the server to finish processing is to have the processing occur in another process after you have sent your response.

`INSERT DELAYED` is a quick-and-dirty way to do this. The database rows to insert will be queued up by MySQL and inserted later. This means there's no way to detect or handle a value error, because after the `execute()` the row hasn't actually been inserted. Looping through the csv and issuing queries must still be done while the client waits.

If this is still too long you will need to construct or use some kind of spool or task queue. In this design, the request is accepted and then passed to a long-running process or placed in a directory and the web response is sent immediately. Meanwhile, another process running on the server scoops up the requests, processes them, and then records the status somewhere (e.g. a database table). There should be another page the user can go to to monitor the status of their task.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even if I send client a message before processing , the website will keep loading and hanging there so they can't access to other page as well until the process done.So what can I do for this problem?

Comment: You either misunderstood my answer, or you have some other problem. You send the client a "we will work on this" message then **close the response**. The *webserver* doesn't process the request, *another process* does.